# What's the specific meaning of ArcMap "FDO error: -2147154947"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase

ArcMap 10.3.1 is giving us an error of "Unable to save edits. FDO error: -2147154947".  This is not contained in the ESRI list of FDO errors: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/ArcObjects/esriGeoDatabase/fdoError.htm

Here is some more information about our environment and under what circumstances the error occurs:

Once a user receives this error, they will continue to receive this error on every subsequent attempt to Save Edits.  The only way we know to fix the problem is to restart ArcMap and lose all edits since the last save.  The database we are using is an ArcGIS 10.3.1 enterprise multi-user geodatabase hosted on MS SQL Server 2012.  The client software we are using to access the database is ArcMap 10.3.1.  There are multiple versions in the database, and each version is being edited by a single user.  We can have as many 16 users editing different versions simultaneously.  Users will typically save edits every 15-20 minutes, and then reconcile and post their edits a couple times a day.  Archiving is enabled on the GDB feature classes, as well as editor tracking.  We have determined that this error number is probably an HRESULT, but we are unable to find any documentation from Esri or Microsoft for this particular error.

What is the specific meaning of this error code and message. In other words, what specifically is preventing ArcMap from saving the edits?

Edit:
The error happened again and this time we were able to retrieve the SDE log file from the client machine. I have substituted "client_machine_name", "database_name" and "feature_class_name" for the actual values for clarity.

> [Fri Feb 24 13:57:07 2017] [619] [client_machine_name] DB_registered_table_trim_state (database_name.DBO.feature_class_name,38063) Execute Immediate error (-1021).
>   [Fri Feb 24 13:57:07 2017] [619] [client_machine_name] Error when updating kept rows in geometry table.
>   [Fri Feb 24 13:57:07 2017] [619] [client_machine_name] Warning: Unable to trim state 38056->38063 for table database_name.DBO.feature_class_name, error = -1021

Comment: Have a look at https://geonet.esri.com/thread/113423

Comment: I would suggest that it's an extended geodatabase (SDE) error disguised as an Esri error... It looks like it's time to contact Esri support. Have a look at your remote database log files first though, all the info I can find is as a lack of space to save error - but it could just as easily be table locked for some reason. Can you explain a bit more about how you're connecting and editing... directly using a version or checkout; is everyone using the same credentials or do they have their own?

Comment: There is space to save on the server.  We are not using checkout replicas; we are using a direct connection to the SDE database, with each user creating and editing their own version.  Users connect with their own credentials (OS authentication), but they are part of a Windows Active Directory group that is mapped to a SQL Server login, and that role is granted Select/Insert/Update/Delete privileges in Arc.

Comment: It sounds like you've setup SDE correctly with respect to the usual pitfalls.. how is your network? Are you accessing via intranet (wired or wireless)  or a thinner connection (WAN)? Intermittent problems can be caused by network issues or (rarely) virus checking, defragmenting or other utility software locking files - but this would be a very rare case. I say it's time to contact Esri support as they have access to resources that are not publicly available.

Comment: Esri tech support has been contacted.  If they are able to provide an answer, I will post it here. The server and workstations are connected by Ethernet LAN. We will double check that virus scanning, defrag, etc. takes place after hours.

Comment: Not 100% sure on this because the method to decode FDO error constants is a pain but here's what I found:

000922 : Specified dimension field, <value>, not found in <value>

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/a3bd05c8-64a6-4dd4-acb3-0d10b021f2f8.htm

Comment: @Ken, sounds promising.  Could you explain exactly how you were able to decode the FDO error constant?

Comment: @tekim The steps are in the link I posted. You'll see it's a clunky process but it might get you close.

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/a3bd05c8-64a6-4dd4-acb3-0d10b021f2f8.htm

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: @PolyGeo after this question has been up for four months you put it on hold as off topic?  "Reproducing" the problem is not relevant because the  the question was not about how to fix the problem, the question was about the meaning of the error message.

Comment: There is no procedure included that enables the error message to be reproduced.  Remember that GIS SE is not a formal GIS support site, and for questions to be answered here by its volunteers, they really need to be lined up.  It is an Esri error message and only they have the source so the responsibility for explaining what condition leads to it must rest with them.

Comment: @PolyGeo I didn't notice a requirement in the help center that states that questions had to concern reproducible problems. Can we not ask "what is the meaning of...?" type of questions? I purposefully made the question about the meaning of the error message rather than the cause/solution because I cannot reproduce it at will. One of the other volunteers may be able to find this error message in some ESRI documentation and could refer me to that documentation, or they may have encountered the error themselves and deduced the meaning.

Comment: You asked a  "what is the meaning of...?" type of question, and it was left open for 4.5 months.  You asked the vendor (who are the most likely to know) and they did not provide an answer.  If one of our volunteers comes across an answer later then they should flag this question to have it re-opened so that they can answer it.  I am just one of [nearly 200 users with the vote to re-open privilege at 3,000](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/27/alltime/gis/2009-06-28?sort=reputationchange) so if you strongly disagree you could use the GIS Chat Room or a Meta GIS SE post to try and convince them.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are in the link I posted.  You'll see it's a clunky process but it might get you close.

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/a3bd05c8-64a6-4dd4-acb3-0d10b021f2f8.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one where you may need to ask your Esri support via a Maintenance contract.

The same error appears in a [GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/182527-unknown-error-code-fdo-error-2147154947) but the Esri response on that informal channel was:

> Have you run into problems with SQLite databases? If, so can you describe them?

Comment: ESRI tech supports said it was "probably" due to a network issue.  Difficult to believe that there was a network issue on a LAN when all of the components are within a few feet of each other and there was no other sign of such a problem, and that SDE is so fragile as to cause the loss of edits for what could only  have been a extremely brief (microseconds) network issue, if there was a network issue at all.